# Ration of sum and Product of Trigonometric expression.

Tags: trigonometry

> If $A,B,C \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\displaystyle\cos(A-B)+\cos(B-C)+\cos (C-A)=-\frac{3}{2}\;,$ Then
>
> $\displaystyle \frac{\sum \cos^3(\theta+A)}{\prod\cos(\theta+A)}\;, $Where $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Given $\displaystyle\cos(A-B)+\cos(B-C)+\cos (C-A)=-\frac{3}{2}\;,$ after expanding, We get

$$(\cos A+\cos B+\cos C)^2+(\sin A+\sin B+\sin C)^2=0$$

So we get $$\cos A+\cos B+\cos C=0$$ and $$\sin A+\sin B+\sin C=0$$

Now How can I solve after that, Help Required, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the sum $$\cos(\theta+A)+\cos(\theta+B)+\cos(\theta+C)$$
$$=\cos\theta (\cos A+\cos B+\cos C)-\sin\theta(\sin A+\sin B+\sin C)$$
$$=0$$
Using the identity $a^3+b^3+c^3=3abc$ if $(a+b+c)=0$, we get
$$\sum \cos^3(\theta +A)=3\prod\cos(\theta+A)$$